# Remove rows based on date and hour in Excel

Tags: excel

I have dataset of date and hours. I need to remove data before 06:00 and after 18:00 to each day. Is there any formula to do that automatically in excel?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use the `FILTER`-function - together with the `MOD` - logic to retrieve the time part of a date. (you will find a lot of explanations about this topic on SO - 0.25 equals to 6:00 and 0.75 to 18:00):

`=FILTER(tblData,(MOD(tblData[Date],1)>=0.25)*(MOD(tblData[Date],1)<=0.75))`

I named my table `tblData` and the field that I am filtering on is `Date`. You might have to adjust this.

[image]